# How could I add the collapse snippet of Bootstrap to my html?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to add [this](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) example of Bootstrap to my code, but I can't.

Here's my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Novo cadastro</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="my_style.css" type="text/css" />   
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                  Collapsible Group Item #1
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
              <div class="panel-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
                  Collapsible Group Item #2
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
                  Collapsible Group Item #3
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does your console give any errors? Also try explaining exactly what it is not doing. Cause it sounds like the editor refuses to insert the code.

Comment: Your code works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/113/

Comment: Please include the code in your question. Don't just post a link to it.

Comment: @Adrift I tested my code on http://jsfiddle.net/CyCd2/2/ and it didn't work again... How did you do that?

Comment: @WoutervanderHouven it is not collapsing as shown here: jsfiddle.net/52VtD/113

Comment: I opened up your jsfiddle link you just posted and it is collapsing.  What browser are you using?  Do you have java script enabled?  What is happening when its not collapsing?  The buttons don't work at all?

Comment: And can you try opening your browsers Javascript console? In Chrome this would be "Ctrl+Shift+J", IE "F12" and "Ctrl+Shift+K" in FF. You can use that to check where the Javascript is going wrong.

Comment: It's already solved, guys! Thank you so much! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's solved now! Thanks for everyone who replied! ;)

Now I'm loading the  `bootstrap.js` and `jquery.js` from their sources, so here it's lines 4 and 5 from http://jsfiddle.net/CyCd2/5/:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Other option would be download `bootstrap.js` and `jquery.js` to the js folder. This issue is concerned to Absolute and Relative path, that I didn't know about and read about here: http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm

Thanks folks!